# Using Qt with DirectX?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, directx

What exactly are my options? I have programs I need to write in [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) and [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX), and I'd like to use [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(toolkit)) for OpenGL, and not have to re-implement half my program for the DirectX components of my task.

I've looked on Google and I have found references to people complaining about [Direct3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Direct3D) being a dependency of Qt, and people talking about implementing QD3DWidget sub-classing QWidget in a similar fashion to QGLWidget, yet nobody talked about how to implement it or where any examples are.

I need help. I want to know if it is possible? What would I need to do to get it working? Has it been done before?

Comment: I know it's really old post, but when I wanted to do this, I searched just like you and didn't find much information. I therefore created this project to support Direct3D while using Qt: https://github.com/giladreich/QtDirect3D
Hope that will help anyone who'll be looking for the same thing in the future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

its pretty straightforward than I thought,

```
-> Create a QWidget
-> Override paintEngine() method, does nothing, just returns NULL
-> Assign HWND to widget->winId()

    #ifdef USE_QTGUI
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        CD3DWidget wndw;    wndw.show();    wndw.resize(1280,960);
        hWnd = wndw.winId();
    #else
        hWnd = CreateAppWindow(name,300,300);
    #endif

       //CD3DWidget class contains only the following definitions
    CD3DWidget::CD3DWidget(QWidget * parent):QWidget(parent){      }
    QPaintEngine *CD3DWidget::paintEngine (){          return NULL;        }
```

Thanks,

CV

Comment: Does this work in the latest QT? Both other answers say that the DirectX support was experimental and was removed

Comment: Hello Tom, I tried this and works perfectly. I was able to run a  DirectX QWidget and an OpenGL QWidget in the same QMainWindow.

Comment: @Tom J Nowell: You don't need any support or integration in the toolkit to use Direct3D by itself, all you need is a native window handle and telling the toolkit to avoid clearing that window. The "experimental removed support" is as far as I understand it an accelerated rendering backend for Qt, which is a whole different thing.

Comment: It seems to work for me but it hangs because I'm doing a while loop to render my stuff.

Answer (score 2):

List of changes:

Qt 4.6 introduces many new features and improvements as well as bugfixes
over the 4.5.x series.

......................

- The experimental Direct3D paint engine has been removed. The reason for
  this is that Nokia focuses on OpenGL for desktop hardware accelerated
  rendering.

......................

Answer (score 1):

For all its worth, [here is how to get Ogre3D's output to a Qt 4.5 window](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=45709). Basically, you grab a rendering surface and you use it to render the output. This is a "Qt in D3D/OpenGL application approach".

Here are OpenGL examples with [Qt 4.5 using OpenGL window](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/examples.html#opengl).

If I understand it correctly, the Direct3D support is experimental and [is only used for painting of windows](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6-snapshot/qt4-intro.html).