# super smooth, full screen fade-in animated popup image on win32

Tags: winapi, qt, opengl, directx

Any ideas on how to implement it with Qt4.7 or with the [native win32 api](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). It's fine to use DirectX (via sth like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641286/using-qt-with-directx)) or OpenGL too. An animation with a semi-transparent window that refreshes in every frame with more opacity is flickering like hell. For now I'm thinking about Windows 7 but WinRT compatibility wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Simply `AnimateWindow(AW_BLEND)` does not work for you? This works perfectly well for me.

Comment: thanks, had no idea about built-in support... I upvoted your comment; not sure how to mark it as a solution.

Comment: ber4444, you should have included @Damon in your comment so that he would be notified about it.  He might create an answer after seeing it or just leave it as a comment.

Comment: Make sure the surface your blitting to is double buffered, this generally gets rid of most flickering issues

Comment: @ber4444 Paste the answer in as your own and accept it a day later.

Comment: @Damon, it's an old question, but pls have a look at the comments on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669(v=vs.85).aspx, they confirm that it does not work with translucent windows which are standard in modern desktop (Aero) and it's explicitly unsupported on ARM (Metro)