# Show video from device driver in QWidget with native window handle (HWND) on QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, video, hwnd

This is related to my previous question [Qt GLWidget in GraphicsScene for fast video display from image data (C++ , Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637677/).

I have been converting and showing video frames via a QPixMapItem in a QGraphicsScene / View, i.e. not with OpenGL.
The conversion is causing a processor load that could be avoided by having said device drivers paint directly to a window, any scaling issues left aside for now.

While I was able to have the video shown to a standalone QWidget->winID() ([QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html), HWND, [Qt::WA_NativeWindow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum), also see [Using Qt with DirectX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641286/)) adding this widget to the scene does not result in video (it is not visible). Multiple inheritance from a QPixMapItem to be able to use [QGraphicsScene::addItem()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem) ("This scene takes ownership of the item.") did not help either.

Is the object losing its WId when it's becoming a child of the scene?
<s>Unfortunately, something else must be off, even when loading a QImage in the item's constructor, nothing is shown. I will have to investigate further.</s>

Edit 1:
The class inherited from QWidget and QGraphicsPixmapItem is able to display a pixmap, as tested with `myWidget->setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage( QImage("test.png") ) );`. My previous image-loader simply was broken.

Showing the widget on top of the GraphicsView is going to be tricky, as scaling and off-view positions will have to be implemented but I doubt this will work glitch-free (and I think it is quite a bit of work).

Answer (score 1):

Displaying `QWidget` in `QGraphicsScene` is quite tricky. See [QGraphicsProxyWidget](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qgraphicsproxywidget.html#details) description for more information. Basically, the widget you see in `QGraphicsView` is not *real* widget. `QGraphicsView` just redirects paint events to the underlying invisible `QWidget`. Apparently, Qt knows nothing about your video redirection, so it can't translate it to the scene.

I think you should not put your widget inside scene. Consider placing it above the graphics view, for example.